# << overloading with integer

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have this files:

Fraction.h

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_FRACTION_H
#define UNTITLED_FRACTION_H

#import "operators.h"

class Fraction {
private:
    int m_numerator;
    int m_denominator;

public:
    Fraction(int numerator, int denominator):m_numerator(numerator),m_denominator(denominator)
    {

    }
    Fraction():m_numerator(0),m_denominator(1)
    {

    }
    void print();
    friend Fraction operator*(const Fraction &m, int value);
    friend Fraction operator*(const Fraction &m, const Fraction &m2);
    friend Fraction operator*(int value, const Fraction &m);
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Fraction &frac);

};


#endif //UNTITLED_FRACTION_H
```

operators.h

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_OPERATORS_H
#define UNTITLED_OPERATORS_H

#include <iosfwd>
#include "Fraction.h"
#include <string>

class Fraction;

Fraction operator*(const Fraction &m, int value);
Fraction operator*(const Fraction &m, const Fraction &m2);
Fraction operator*(int value, const Fraction &m);
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Fraction &frac);

int gcd(int a, int b);
#endif //UNTITLED_OPERATORS_H
```

operators.cpp

```
#include "operators.h"

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Fraction &frac)
{
    out << frac.m_numerator << "/" << std::to_string(frac.m_denominator);
    return out;
}
```

I get an error in operators.cpp saying:

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const int')
```

But in https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/ they do the same and works. It looks like I can't concatenate the std::ostream with an integer but this normally works when we concatenate ostreams and integers in std::cout - i.e. std::cout << "Hello " << 4;

Comment: Looks like you've forgotten `#include <iostream>`

Comment: Which compiler you r using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, did you tried `#include <iostream>` in operators.cpp? Because as far as I know, "<<" is defined in iostream

Comment: It is actually the `std::ostream` type, among others, that is defined in `<iostream>`.  It is the OP's code that is trying to define the `operator<<()`, and that requires visibility of the relevant type definition.